# Dataset of electro-mechanical data storage devices prices and storage capabilities

Tags: data-request, global, technology

I am looking for a data set of electro-mechanical data storage devices prices and specs. In particular, I am interested in the prices of memory storage (e.g. Hard Disk, Solid State Hardisk etc. etc.) comparing the $/GB, writing reading speed, the maximum capacity and so on I did my own table. But I want to validate it against a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

[Hard Drive Data and Stats](https://www.kaggle.com/jackywangkaggle/hard-drive-data-and-stats?)

Hard drive failure data and stats from 2019

Except price you can find the other detailed dataset here:

The first row of each file contains the column names, the remaining rows are the actual data. The columns are as follows:

- Date – The date of the file in yyyy-mm-dd format.
- Serial Number – The manufacturer-assigned serial number of the drive.
- Model – The manufacturer-assigned model number of the drive.
- Capacity – The drive capacity in bytes.
- Failure – Contains a “0” if the drive is OK. Contains a “1” if this is the last day the drive was operational before failing.